# How to display HTML string resource with parameters in TextView?

Tags: java, android, html, string, textview

I have a HTML string like this:

```
Some text %1$s
<br></br>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOvewflow</a>
<br></br>
Contact: <a href="mailto:example@gmail.com">example@gmail.com</a>
```

How to display it so it shows the line breaks and links to the text properly in a TextView?

I have tried both

```
Spanned text = null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text, "parameter"), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
}
else
{
    text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text, "parameter"));
}
textView.setText(text);
```

and

```
String text = TextUtils.htmlEncode(getString(R.string.text, "parameter"));
textView.setText(text);
```

In the XML textView is defined as

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="@string/text"
        />
```

When displayed, it just looks like

```
Some text parameter StackOvewflow Contact: example@gmail.com
```

without any line breaks or links

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code you shared

```
  Spanned text = null;
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text, "parameter"), 
    Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
  }
  else
  {
    text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text), "parameter");
  }
  textView.setText(text);
```

seems to be working fine for me.
[image]

> seems to be working

Comment: Does it really? Shouldn't the `text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text), "parameter");`  line give error and should actually be `text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text, "parameter"));`? It does not work on my programs.

Comment: are u getting any exceptions ?, try putting the code in a try/catch or check your logs

Comment: No exceptions. This is the only thing I see that may be some problem? `W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>`

Comment: `Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>`